# Ionic 3 Set notification permission on toggle button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to know how can i use notification permission in ionic app on toggle button. I want when user turn off the toggle so user cant get FCM Push notification if toggle is on then the user can get notification. I try to use local storage when user turn off toggle i set the toggle false in localstoreage so when the user open app again the toggle button is off .

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="isToggled" (ionChange)="notify()" item-start checked="true" ></ion-toggle>
        <ion-label item-end style="text-align: right;">تلقي الاشعارات
</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

.ts

```
  constructor(private nativeStorage: NativeStorage, private push: Push, public platform: Platform, private fcm: FCM,  public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {


    this.initializeApp();

  }

  initializeApp() {
       this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.check();

      //Notifications
      if(this.isToggled == true){
      this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all');
      this.fcm.getToken().then(token=>{
          console.log(token);
      })
      this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data=>{

        if(data.wasTapped){
                this.nav.setRoot(ArticledetailsPage, {x:data.newsid});

          console.log("Received in background");
        } else {
          console.log("Received in foreground");
        };
      })
      if(this.isToggled == true){
        this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('marketing');
      }

      else{
      this.fcm.unsubscribeFromTopic('marketing');
      }

      //end notifications.

      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }



        notification(){
  this.nav.push(NotificationPage);
  }

public notify() {
  console.log("Toggled: "+ this.isToggled); 
  this.nativeStorage.setItem('toggle', {property: this.isToggled, anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );

}

check(){
  this.nativeStorage.getItem('toggle')
  .then(
    (data) => {
    console.log(data.property),
    this.isToggled = data.property;
    console.log(this.isToggled);
    }
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Simple in your notify() function you get the value of your user toggled is false or true when application is open if the toggle value is true then             `this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all');` . and if it false so just unsubscribe it. Hope this is your perfect answer

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.check();

      //Notifications
      this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
        console.log(token);
      })
      this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {

        if (data.wasTapped) {
          this.nav.setRoot(ArticledetailsPage, { x: data.newsid });

          console.log("Received in background");
        } else {
          console.log("Received in foreground");
        };
      })


      //end notifications.

      if (this.isToggled == true) {
        this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all');
      }

      else {
        this.fcm.unsubscribeFromTopic('all');
      }

      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }



  notification() {
    this.nav.push(NotificationPage);
  }

  public notify() {
    console.log("Toggled: " + this.isToggled);
    this.nativeStorage.setItem('toggle', { property: this.isToggled, anotherProperty: 'anotherValue' })
      .then(
        () => console.log('Stored item!'),
        error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
      );
    if (this.isToggled == true) {
      this.fcm.unsubscribeFromTopic('all');
    }
    else {
      this.fcm.unsubscribeFromTopic('all');
    }
  }

  check() {
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('toggle')
      .then(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data.property),
            this.isToggled = data.property;
          console.log(this.isToggled);
        }
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing that proper way is write backend function to register unregister notification

```
Eg : /myapi/stopPushnotification
```

This one which remove/add the token from our database or keep track it to another table. On the app we have toggle that turns it on and off. it is the best way to do .

Answer (score 0):

1) create a service

```
notification service.ts
====================
appConfig = {
 pushNotificationStatus : true    // false
```

}

2) Make a service call to enable/disable pushNotificationStatus on toggle button and update the value in `notification service.ts` appconfig as:-

```
// suppose putservice call for enable/disable push notification

constructor(public notifServ: NotificationService){}
ontoggle(){
 this.https.post(url,{}).subscribe(res =>{
  this.notifServ.appConfig.pushNotificationStatus = true // false based on service call
})
}
```

3) `app.component.ts or component load`, check pushNotification is enabled or disabled 
   for app in some call(may be profile call or any call that sends  pushNotification status 
   of user for app)
  a) do call and update value in

```
this.notifServ.appConfig.pushNotificationStatus = true // false
```

Or,

Doing this in localStorage is not the best way but can be done if you want to handle it at client level:-

```
For this, whenever your component loads `clear localStorage` or set `push notiifcation key` in localStorage as empty or null or may delete.
```

Note: The above first method ie `service also works at client level`, `just update the  appConfig in service and use it as refrence when do enable/disable push notifications.`